# VM configuration file .vmx got corrupted while editing with date sync parameters

Tags: virtual-machine

I am running VM Machine (VMware workstation 12 player) on Windows 10. I need to set date to in past on VM .
I have followed the procedures mentioned at the following links.

[VMWare how to prevent a virtual machine from updating its date and time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23699147/vmware-how-to-prevent-a-virtual-machine-from-updating-its-date-and-time)
http://www.woodwardweb.com/technology/freezing_time_i.html

VM was powered off, Configuration file was modified with following statements using "Notepad".

```
tools.syncTime = "FALSE"
time.synchronize.continue = "FALSE"
time.synchronize.restore = "FALSE"
time.synchronize.resume.disk = "FALSE"
time.synchronize.shrink = "FALSE"
time.synchronize.tools.startup = "FALSE"
time.synchronize.tools.enable = "FALSE"
time.synchronize.resume.host = "FALSE"
```

After the modifications to file, when I start VM it says .vmx got corrupt. Again I have to create .vmx from .log file.

How to edit .vmx file without corrupting or am I missing any thing.

As mentioned my HOST is Windows 10 and GUEST is VMware Workstation 12 Player.

Thanks & Regards